# Java if-statement with equals comparison always evaluates to true

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison, integer, equals

I am fairly new to Java and every time I try to compare input to temp, I get all of the results in my array, even if input and temp are not the same.

Code:

```
if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) 
{ 
    String temp; 
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        { 
            temp = Integer.toString(Read.tempHigh[i]);

            if ( input.equals(temp) );
            {   
                j.TextArea3.append(temp);
                j.TextArea3.append(input);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {   
        jTextArea3.append("Please enter a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect your code does not contain the critical part. Have you debugged your code? pPlace a breakpoint at the line of the if statement and look at the contents of input and temp. One of them will contain a value you do not expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line...

```
if ( input.equals(temp) );
```

Should not have the `;` at the end of it. The `;` symbol is closing the if-statement off, so it will always run the `j.TextArea3.append()` lines no matter what the values of `input` and `temp` are.

Your code above should therefore look like this...

```
if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){ 
    String temp; 
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){ 
            temp = Integer.toString(Read.tempHigh[i]);

            if ( input.equals(temp) ) {   
                j.TextArea3.append(temp);
                j.TextArea3.append(input)
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){   
        jTextArea3.append("Please enter a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks you! I been trying to figure out what was messing it up for so long.

Comment: No problem - its easy to miss.